# Selenium/Python2.7 Check if elements in list matches one on the web page

Tags: python, selenium, element, src

```
from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.set_window_size(1400, 1000)
driver.get('')

list_of_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('img[title][src*=images]')

srcs = [ele.get_attribute("src") for ele in list_of_elements]
print srcs
```

My above code prints out the src links of images on a webpage. The links all look like http://example.com/test.gif, now I have a list of the 'test' part of the images that I want to click on if they appear. So what I need is to check through the 'srcs' list and when it matches a 'test' it clicks on that image. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to prepare a `set` of the desired filenames beforehand, extract the filename from the `src` attribute for every matched image and check if the filename is in the set:

```
import re 

filenames = {"test1", "test2", "test3"}  # this is a set

pattern = re.compile(r"/(\w+)\.gif$")

result = []
for ele in list_of_elements:
    src = ele.get_attribute("src")
    match = pattern.search(src)
    if match:
        filename = match.group(1)
        if filename in filenames:  # since "filenames" is  a set, lookups are O(1)
            result.append(filename)

print(result)
```